# macOS - Terminal - find and remove folder in the Users directory older than X days

Tags: macos, terminal

I work for a school and I'd like to send out a script to delete user folders older than X days on lab computers.

I've come up with:

```
find /Users/* -prune -mtime 30 | grep -v /Users/admin | grep -v /Users/Shared
```

That returns the directories other than those 2 directories that are older than 30 days, which is great, but I'm not quite sure how to now delete those folders.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `grep`ing the results to skip certain folders, use the `-not -path` options with `find`.

```
find /Users/* -prune -not -path /Users/Shared -not -path /Users/admin -mtime 30
```

Then you can use `-exec` to `rm -rf` each entry.

```
find /Users/* -prune -not -path /Users/Shared -not -path /Users/admin -mtime 30 -exec rm -rf "{}" \;
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks much!

Comment: I am having to add "sudo" before the rm -rf command, and then I'm prompted for a password. Is there a way to automate it to either not ask for the password, or to include that password? Thanks!

Comment: @theBrofessor You will want to run this command as root. If you are running it automatically, make sure the script is run as root.

Comment: @alexander-omara Thank you so much!